# PSD TO HTML ( Source PSD with High Width )

Tags: psd

I have PSD with this specification :

2846 as Width.

[image]

The paragraph with this font size settings :

> 43.75 px 
>   50 px
>   Metrics
>   VA 0

I'm familiar with 1170 px site width.

What should i do with this psd?

To determine site width and font spesification for each element?

Comment: Are you going to build the site in HTML or do you mean you want some kind of quick converter? 

If you can't scale things accordingly in your head, maybe resize the PSD to 1366px width (arguably the most common screen size) and then you can build the site at a 1 to 1 scale.

Comment: Hi. I want to use HTML + CSS. Do you mean image resize from Image > Image Size? I have tried it, but the font size looks unfamiliar, example 45.99 px for size and 23.04 for spacing.

Comment: Based on above image link, my content is not started from 0px, should i eliminate it first? Sorry for sillly question.

Comment: Oh, so you have padding around your PSD? It would certainly help you to chop that off.

Also, what's wrong with a font of 45.99px? Just round it up to 46px when coding HTML...